# Renderscript code completion

Tags: android, android-studio, renderscript, android-renderscript

I'm using Android Studio 3.0 to write renderscript code. But I see that it **doesn't support code completion for .rs files.**

The official Renderscript documentation doesn't mention anything about code completion.

Is there any setting that needs to be changed to enable code completion for renderscript files in Android Studio? Or is there any alternative IDE( preferably online IDE ) for code completion for renderscript code?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No, Android Studio (nor Intellij IDEA) does not support code completion in Renderscript code.

Answer (score 0):

When a new RenderScript file is created an associated class in Java has to be created. Which is done by clicking **`Build > Rebuild Project`** in Android Studio. Once the build process is completed, the linking Java class is created.

Other than this there is no other way to compile RenderScript files.